# Spacing Between Divs on a Site

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project, and I need the black `div`s to be much closer together on the top and bottom. Also I need the `div`s to be in the center of the page. How would I do this with CSS?

HTML:

```
<div class="statuses">
    <div class="na">
      <h5>North America</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="br">
      <h5>Brazil</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="eune">
      <h5>Europe Nordic and East</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="euw">
      <h5>Europe West</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="lan">
      <h5>Latin America North</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="las">
      <h5>Latin America South</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="oce">
      <h5>Oceania</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ru">
      <h5>Russia</h5>
    </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <h5>Turkey</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="pbe">
    <h5>Public Beta Environment</h5>
  </div>
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
.na , .br , .eune , .euw , .lan , .las , .oce , .ru , .tr , .pbe
{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 425px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;

}
```

A screenshot of the current result:
[image: Screenshot of the black <code>div</code>s overlaid on an image, demonstrating the described issue.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the default margins those `<h5>`s are getting:

```
h5 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

In order to center them, you need to set the right and left margins to 'auto'. Here's a jsfiddle with both things: https://jsfiddle.net/jameson5555/uead1cL4/

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the "h5" headline tag with CSS by doing something like this:

```
{
// Remove spaces
margin: 0px;   
// Centered text
text-align: center;
}
```